# How to print multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and i want to print this array but the key values should print once at first time and after that always print array values.

```
array(
  array(
    'Name'=> 'Trixie',
    'Color'=> 'Green',
    'Element'=> 'Earth',
    'Likes'=> 'Flowers'
    ),
  array(
    'Name'=> 'Tinkerbell',
    'Element'=> 'Air',
    'Likes'=> 'Singning',
    'Color'=> 'Blue'
    ),  
  array(
    'Element'=> 'Water',
    'Likes'=> 'Dancing',
    'Name'=> 'Blum',
    'Color'=> 'Pink'
    ),
 );
```

And expect this output:

```
Name        Color  Element  Likes  
Trixie      Green  Earth    Flowers 
Tinkerbell  Blue   Air      Singing 
Blum        Pink   Water    Dancing
```

Comment: why not sort the keys first then print them with a simple loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$yourarray = array(
   array(
    'Name'=> 'Trixie',
    'Color'=> 'Green',
    'Element'=> 'Earth',
    'Likes'=> 'Flowers'
    ),
array(
    'Name'=> 'Tinkerbell',
    'Element'=> 'Air',
    'Likes'=> 'Singning',
    'Color'=> 'Blue'
    ),  
array(
    'Element'=> 'Water',
    'Likes'=> 'Dancing',
    'Name'=> 'Blum',
    'Color'=> 'Pink'
    ),
);



echo "<table>";

echo "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Color</td><td>Element</td><td>Likes</td></tr>";


foreach($yourarray as $value){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$value['Name']."</td><td>".$value['Color']."</td><td>".$value['Element']."</td><td>".$value['Likes']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}



echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$x = //the array

//get the keys from the first item in the array and loop
foreach (array_keys($x[0]) as $key) {
   //echo each key
   echo $key;
 }

 //loop the array
 foreach ($x as $arr) {
   //loop each item of the sub array
   foreach ($arr as $v) {
     //echo item's value
     echo $v;
   }
 }
```

Comment: `TrixieGreeNEarthFlowersTinkerbellAirSingningBlueWaterdancingBlumPink` is not exactly what the OP wants...

Comment: @MarcB Oops, I should have spent more time on that. CarbonBasedLifeform's answer is certainly better.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:
Live demo : https://eval.in/90748

```
 $arr = array(
    array(
        'Name'=> 'Trixie',
        'Color'=> 'Green',
        'Element'=> 'Earth',
        'Likes'=> 'Flowers'
    ),
    array(
        'Name'=> 'Tinkerbell',
        'Element'=> 'Air',
        'Likes'=> 'Singning',
        'Color'=> 'Blue'
    ),
    array(
        'Element'=> 'Water',
        'Likes'=> 'Dancing',
        'Name'=> 'Blum',
        'Color'=> 'Pink'
    ),
);
echo "Name  Color   Element Likes"."<br />";
foreach($arr as $ar){
    echo $ar['Name']." ".$ar['Color']." ".$ar['Element']." ".$ar['Likes']."<br />";
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Name  Color   Element Likes
Trixie Green Earth Flowers
Tinkerbell Blue Air Singning
Blum Pink Water Dancing
```